# R, ggplot 2 bar graph x axis tick mark names disappear

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm new to R and programming so please forgive me if this is a simple fix. I'm trying to label my x-axis tick marks on a bar graph in ggplot2 but when I run the code the entire x-axis tick-mark names disappear and I'm only left with the axis title.

[Here is a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nolm4.png)

Here is my code:

```
#creating a bar graph of the "income" varibale

bar_graph_income <- ggplot(PRCPS, aes(income)) + geom_bar() + labs(title 
= "How much money are American families making?", subtitle = "Pew 
Research April 17 Political Survey") + labs(x="Income Ranges", y="Survey 
Responses") + theme_bw() 

#creating breaks and naming ticks 

bar_graph_income <- bar_graph_income + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9") , labels=c("1" = "Below $10,000", "2" = "$10,000-$19,999", "3" = "$20,000-$29,999", "4" = "$30,000-$39,999", "5" = "$40,000-$49,999", "6" = "$50,000-$74,999", "7" = "$75,000-$99,999", "8" = "$100,000-$149,999", "9" = "$150,000 or more"))

#changing the text of the title

bar_graph_income <- bar_graph_income + theme(plot.title=element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=14))

#changing the rest of the text

bar_graph_income<- bar_graph_income + theme(axis.text = element_text(family="Times", size=12, colour="black"))

#calling bar_graph_income

bar_graph_income
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little difficult to diagnose without sample data, but I believe the issue is caused because you are calling `scale_x_discrete` on continuous data (`income`).

You can get around this by setting `limits` first:

```
bar_graph_income <- bar_graph_income +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=1:9, labels = c("Below $10,000", "$10,000-$19,999", "$20,000-$29,999",
                                          "$30,000-$39,999", "$40,000-$49,999", "$50,000-$74,999",
                                          "$75,000-$99,999", "$100,000-$149,999", "$150,000 or more"))
```

You can also do this in one call with `ggplot2`:

```
bar_graph_income <- ggplot(PRCPS, aes(income)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  labs(title = "How much money are American families making?", 
       subtitle = "Pew Research April 17 Political Survey",
       x = "Income Ranges", y = "Survey Responses") + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=1:9, labels = c("Below $10,000", "$10,000-$19,999", "$20,000-$29,999",
                                          "$30,000-$39,999", "$40,000-$49,999", "$50,000-$74,999",
                                          "$75,000-$99,999", "$100,000-$149,999", "$150,000 or more")) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=14),
        axis.text = element_text(family="Times", size=12, colour="black"))
```

Alternatively, you can mutate your `income` field as a factor (`as.factor`) and set the levels appropriately before calling `ggplot`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! The reason I set it as discrete is because its survey data from 1-9 with each number representing a specific income range. I really appreciate your help